# Another capacitor like component

Tags: components, identification

Sorry (as in the previous post I said it would be the last component question).

However, this one I also cannot find:

They both look very similar:

I had to put them on some other components to fix them into place for making a better picture.

The left one shows: 806, SVP, 180 16
The right one: (onknown symbol) A 85K, 1500 2.5V

Initially I thought these are transistors (since they have 2 legs and look like them), but they are not (I think).

I'm almost sure these come from a computer VGA card (old one).

[image]

Comment: Both almost certainly capacitors. Look very much like standard SMD electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: Transistors have three leads.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spehro spotted the OSCON SVP, the other one has:

- a fancy fashionable blue color which looks like Nichicon LF but the markings are wrong
- 1500µV/2.5V points to a polymer cap, to be used on PC motherboard or GPU
- the tiny "crown" on top of the "A" is actually the [Nippon Chemi-Con](https://www.chemi-con.co.jp/e/catalog/aluminum.html) logo

[image]

- Markings are very similar to other Nippon ChemiCon polymer caps, so I think we have an identification, but hard to say what series they are though.

"85K" is not a temperature, rather a serial/lot number.

Now, since you say you are a beginner:

If you want to reuse these caps, mind the fact that the [ESR](https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/abacus/resources/engineers-insight/article/understanding-esr-in-electrolytic-capacitors) will be extremely low, most likely below 0.010 Ohms, so if you use them at the output of a voltage regulator or LDO you need to check its datasheet to be sure the regulator/LDO will be stable with such a low ESR capacitor. LM317 dislikes low ESR caps, for example it can be unstable or oscillate.

Also polymer caps often have very high leakage currents (like 1mA) so not for use in low-power circuits.

On a CPU/GPU you would have a buck DC-DC converter which converts ATX 12V supply into 1-1.2V high current, like 10-100 amps, hence the ultra low ESR, which does not make "better" caps, just specialized for this use. The OSCON is 16V so it would be on the 12V input, the blue one is 2.5V so it would be on the output, along with tons of ceramics.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info ... and yes, I'm a beginner, I even don't understand everything you write, but most important is to be careful not to reuse it ... I didn't have any plans so far. I just want to increase my knowledge (so thanks for the explanation).

Answer (score 7):

Electrolytic capacitors. 180uF/16V and 1500uF/2.5V. They are the polarized type. The stripe on the top indicates the cathode (negative) lead.

The SVP is possibly [Panasonic organic polymer](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/315/SVP_OS-262396.pdf) type (low impedance and a bit expensive), though the case size marking does not appear to match, so it may be a low-cost clone of unknown characteristics.

[image]

Edit: Check out @peufeu for the other cap information (+1)

Comment: Thanks ... I got confused not seeing the uF symbol :-) 
I'm still quite new into electronics.

Comment: Got the other one ;)